# The sum of character of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. A character of $G$ is a homomorphism $\chi: G \to K^*$, where $K^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of a field $K$. From the definition of $\chi$, it follows that $\chi(g)$ is a root of unity for any $g \in G$.

I am stuck that $\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) = 0$ for a non-trivial character $\chi: G \to K^*$. I know $\sum_{g \in \langle a \rangle}\chi(g) = 0$ if $G=\langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic group. How to prove the fact that $\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) = 0$ for any finite group $G$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, what happened if $\chi$ is the trivial character, $\chi(g) = 1$ $\forall g \in G$ ?

Comment: @  N.H. Thank you very much.  I require that $\chi$ is a non-trivial character.

Comment: Ok. I did answer to your question, but I don't know if this is easy to deduce without orthogonality relations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characters verify an orthogonality property : if $\chi$ is not isomorphic to $\chi'$ then $\langle \chi, \chi' \rangle = 0$ (assuming they are both irreducible, but here any 1-dimensional character is by definition irreducible).
If $\chi$ is not the trivial character, then $\chi$ is not isomorphic to the trivial character $1$. In particular, $\langle \chi, 1 \rangle = 0$ and it follows that $\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) = 0$.

Edit : as pointed Alex Youcis in the comment, there is a simpler way of seeing it. If $\chi$ is non-trival, there is $g_0$ with $\chi(g_0) \neq 1$. But then $\sum_{g} \chi(g) = \sum_{g} \chi(g_0g) = \chi(g_0) \sum_g \chi(g)$ and therefore $\sum_g \chi(g) = 0$.

Comment: This is way overkill (although definitely good to recognize it as a basic case of orthogonality)--+1. Since $\chi$ is non-trivial you can choose $g_0$ such that $\chi(g_0)\ne 1$. Then, $\displaystyle \chi(g_0)\sum_g \chi(g)$ equals $\displaystyle \sum_g \chi(g_0g)=\sum_g\chi(g)$ by reindexing. But, since $\chi(g_0)\ne 1$ this implies that $\displaystyle \sum_g \chi(g)=0$.

Comment: Oh you're totally right ! You should post this as an answer, this is way more elementary than my solution.

Comment: No need to clutter the answers--you can just edit yours and add it as an alternative way of seeing it.

Comment: Sure, thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @ N.H. and Alex Youcis Thank you very much.

Comment: Notice that this property is a very general fact : if $G$ is a locally compact group (e.g. a finite group) and $m$ the right Haar measure on $G$, then any non-trivial character $\chi : G  \to S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^*$ satisfy
$\displaystyle \int_G \chi \; dm = 0$

Comment: Having stumbled across this while doing something else, I don't think the original idea was overkill at all. I think it is more natural than reindexing, which always feels... *dirty*.

Comment: Why is $\chi(g_0)\sum_g\chi(g)=\sum_g \chi(g_0 g)$? Also, how about $\chi(g_0)=0$?

Comment: The second "argument" doesn't seem to use the condition that the representation is irreducible. At least it doesn't explain how this is used. And the original claim is false in case the rep is not irreducible - just take a sum of two trivial ones...